# Discord bot maker gif

Tags: bots, discord

I used the discord bot maker app and made a bot to send a gif via url link when a command is typed. I type "$image[insert gif url link] and then type the command but it loads in as a grey square. How can I fix this.

Edit: and image file works fine. It's only gif that doesn't. For example if I put a direct url link in $image for a png or jpeg it works great. But not gif

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To answer your question we need to see what you've tried so far, by showing us your code and results.